# Login Parameter in Json in Android

Tags: android, json, json-api

I want to **Compare Parameters** whether both username and password is true and if not then print something wrong in dialog box.Validation of Username and Password in android.when username not matches with password it should show dialog box that username is not true.

```
  public class MainActivity extends   
  AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginid);
    final EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpass);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = id.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("username", username)
                        .add("password", password)
                        .build();


                    try {
                        post(ConstantValues.BASE_URL, formBody, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                                Log.e("JSONDemo", "IOException", e);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                String res = response.body().string();

                                Log.e("res", " " + res);
                                try {

                                    JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(res);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {


                                        JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                                        final String namee = jsonobj.getString("FIRST_NAME");




                                        Log.e("name", " " + namee);

                                    }
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            // you can access all the UI componenet


                                        }
                                    });


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("JSONDemo", "onResponse", e);


                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("JSONDemo", "Post Exception", e);
                    }


            }
        }
    });
}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}


private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Call post(String url, RequestBody formBody, Callback callback) throws IOException {

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}

public void showAlertDialog(String title, String message) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder1.setTitle(title);
    builder1.setMessage(message);
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            builder1.show();

        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue or problem you are facing ?

Comment: username and password from API match and it displays name in dialog box but what i do if username and password not match in API in android can u pls tell me thanks in advance

Comment: show me your all response like if success then what response coming from server, or if failure then what response you are getting

Comment: i had printed whole program of json in this there is not more in this program.....actually when it is success it automatically place name in dialog of that particular user...

Comment: I am not asking for coding, i am asking for response, what are you getting in this  Log.e("res", " " + res); that i want to see for each scenario like invalid user, invalid password, invalid authentication and all

Comment: so just pass some wrong inputs and check response there and put it here

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for FIRST_NAME

Comment: this is coming...... when i had passed wrong input.

Comment: this will be for this Log.e("name", " " + namee);

show for  Log.e("res", " " + res);

Comment: E/JSONDemo: onResponse
                                                                    org.json.JSONException: No value for FIRST_NAME
                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
                                                                        at 
this is the only error my loge shows

Comment: after string namee it directly moves out so log.e("JsonDemo","onResponse",e) is showing

Comment: Then you need to put your own message in catch block as invalid credentials, show you can show dialog from catch block with error message

Comment: is there anyother way lyk use has(string) or else  coz try and catch for error handling.

Comment: you should get error message from response, and there for I am asking that show me response, because there are always response from server like user not exists or invalid username or password which you can show in dialog

Comment: E/JSONDemo: onResponse
                                org.json.JSONException: No value for FIRST_NAME

Comment: ok where i put log coz i am seeing only one log....and logcat shows only one loge

Comment: do debug in your app and put debug point at Log.e("res", " " + res); this line and check what you get in res

Comment: i had putted wrong input and got this on Log.e("res", " " + res);
  {
    "SUCCESS": "0"
  }
]

Comment: Exactly from initial I am asking for this, now you can check the value of SUCCESS and if it is 1 then success so check for name and if it is not 1 then error so show error message

Comment: but how i am new in android development.....do i write if(SUCCESS==1){true}else{this}....Can u please provide me syntax i got it what you said and i am grateful that you made this much effort thanks

Comment: For that post two response here 1 for success login and 2 for invalid login so I can give you proper code

Comment: yes please give me proper code.I am somewhat confused i had put if(namee.isequals("SUCCESS")

Comment: First show me both full response for success login and invalid login

Comment: Invalid:-------------response = {Response@4279} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.1.55/services/appservices.asmx/Login}"
res = "[\r\n  {\r\n    "SUCCESS": "0"\r\n  }\r\n]"

Comment: valid:-----------[
  {
   
   
    "FIRST_NAME": "PRAVIN",   
       "PRODUCT_ID": "2,7,5,11,9,8,3,4",
    "DISTRIBUTION_REQUIRED": true,
    "SUCCESS": "1"
  }
]

Comment: check my answer just replace onResponse method by below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply below code for your response method:

```
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

     String res = response.body().string();

     Log.e("res", " " + res);

      try {

             JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(res);

             for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {


                JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                final String result = jsonobj.getString("SUCCESS");

                String namee = "";

                if(result.equals(“1”)
                {
                    namee = jsonobj.getString("FIRST_NAME");
                }
                else
                {
                    namee = "Invalid Username or Password";
                }

                Log.e("name", " " + namee);

             }
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    // you can access all the UI componenet
                 }
           });

       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("JSONDemo", "onResponse", e);
  }
```

Comment: great thanks alot now i get your code can you please provide me email ID so that in future if i had some query i can contact you.

Comment: you can directly contact by this answer also anytime comment here, as stackoverflow has no policy to share personal details here

Comment: ok thanks alot as you helped me so much thumbs up for your effort :)

Comment: how to set activity in fragment i am using navigation drawer?